# Is it safe to store collection name in class of firestore Project class file?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are making a Firestore query by using collection name, so I thought to store collection name in a static class, or in the same class something like:

```
 private static final String collUsers = "users";
```

and then use something like `db.collections(collUsers).documents()`

So is it safe to store collection names in fields?

Comment: i'm not sure why this wouldn't be safe - how else would you retrieve the collections without a reference to the name being somewhere ? the alternative to this would just be using the names directly in the queries, but either way the collection names would be _somewhere_ in your app, regardless ?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you mean by "safe".  It's kind of a broad term.  What are you concerned about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it safe to store the collection name in the class of Firestore Project class file?

Sure, it is. The collection names are always Strings. You can use them directly in your reference:

```
db.collections("users").documents()
```

Or you can save that name in a variable. However, if you do that, that variable becomes a constant, as the name of the collection cannot be changed. So most probably the variable name might look like this:

```
public static final String USERS_COLLECTION = "users";
```

So the problem is **not** that you keep these names in your project file, the problem is how you read, write, and delete the data that exists there. In that case, you should always secure that data using [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Comment: sure one more query in same context, is it safe to store , firestore, auth, FirebaseStorage instance in a variable, or should i use it directly? Does calling get instance on Auth, FirebaseStorage, FirebaseStore return different instance or same instance everytime?

Comment: Yes, you can store them in a variable because will always return the same instance. This is happening because all of them are Singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe to keep your query for firestore open, until you have firestore rules in place which guard your data against any misuse and edits.

If you want to know more about securing your data: [Read this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query)